# What is a good Django app for scheduled reminders send to users by email

Tags: django, django-apps

Google, Github and Stackoverflow bring up django-schedule and django-mailer, but these are both old projects with not much development, if at all in the last ~ 2years.

My use case:

User sets him/herself reminders to be send by email. A reminder is simply a chunk of text, some fields to determine when to send the reminder.

Reminders can be repeating daily or weekly. Reminders can also be one-off reminders.

Is there a good, current app for this with Django 1.3/1.4? Perhaps the solution is to write the reminder models myself, and then send with some scheduler - django-celery or django-cronograph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you going to do it by yourself, try the Advanced Python Scheduler:

http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/

It's useful especially when you can not or will not use the cron.